# store values after page being refreshed in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have a simple classic asp page where two drop downs are there namely employ name and employee number. After selecting the respective values a button is there named add row which will simply add row. As many rows can be added.
Page is not being post back and there is no login or logout.
My problem is that I want to store values of all rows after page is being refreshed? How can I do that?

Comment: Before posting a question could I recommend you visit [ask]

Comment: Where do you want to store the values? Do you want to write them to a database or just preserve them on the page.  If it's the latter then do a bit of research on how to use `Request.Form("")`

Comment: John I want to preserve them but main problem is that I am not using any post or get method. When I refresh the page data in the drop down values should be intact as it is.

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the page the browser issues a GET request to the server. The server generates the html and sends it back to the browser so in order "to remember" the values you've entered so far you have to implement some way of passing those values back and forward between the browser and the server.
You'll need to post the values when add row is clicked and store them in session or db. Take a look here http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp

Comment: I don't have db and I used sessions and tried to store value of drop down into that but the session variable is not storing that.to confirm that I had written response.write(session (variable name)) and it is not showing anything.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. You just need to try harder :) before doing this with your problem just do an example of how to store/retrieve data in session and you'll be fine

Comment: I have tried to store and retrieve data from sessions and it is working fine but with drop down list all stop working

Comment: You need to put those dropdowns in a form so that they can be serialized and posted when you click the button, and have in mind that what you'll get is their value instead of the display text.

Comment: I have these dropdowns in a form and yup I know I will get the value. Do you know how to get value of control if the method is get. When method is post we write request.form() and for get what we have to write if we want to get control value?

Comment: As the question was not clear in the first place you could have saved us all a lot of hassle by not attempting to answer it.